# jquery validate does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

As simple as the code below looks, I struggle to find the error (and I checked various examples; when I enter the submitform button without no value in the form field I'd expect a jquery validation message but nothing happens. I did notice a (quick dissapearing) message in the console field "Uncaught type error: "Cannot read property of 'param' of null" (???)

Any idea where I go wrong? Another question: does jquery.validate require the id tag value to be equal to the name tage value?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/additional-methods.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

        <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="post" autocomplete="on">

        <label class="field2" for="productname1"> Product naam </label> <input id="productname1" type="text" name="productname1"> <br>

        <input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Submit Form">
        </form>

<script>

    $("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
            // simple rule

            productname1: {
                required:true
            }


            } //rules
    }); //validate()


</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using version 1.4.2 of jQuery, jQuery Validation plugin hasn't been tested with jQuery versions lower than 1.6.4 and simply migth not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working fine. Check your code at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/gLpHY/)

Try with different version of jQuery, as `validate()` might be conflicting with jQuery 1.4 plugin.

Try [new version](http://jquery.com) of jquery

Comment: completely overlooked that, thnx (!)